# Android balanced-api import error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, balanced-payments

I've been having issues importing the balanced-api for Android into eclipse. I cloned the project from their git repo: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-android

However every time I attempt to import the project I receive the following error:

"Cannot nest 'balanced-android/src/main/java' inside 'balanced-android/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'balanced-android/src'

I'm also not to sure what this error really means, so perhaps if someone could explain it that might prove helpful.

Screenshot:
[image: Balanced-api Android import error]

I have tried on several occasions with no success. Of course I have also tried restarting eclipse, recloning the project but still with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ADT functions differently and Android development environments and project structures vary, I can provide you with some tips on how I've imported balanced-android into an application using ADT, however, your mileage may vary.

- Go to Help -> Install New Software...
- Select "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" for the "Work with" field
- Expand "General Purpose tools"
- Select "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse"
- Accept the license and install. Restart ADT.
- File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects
- Navigate to balanced-android/balanced-android (NOTE the nested directory. The balanced-android library project is named "balanced-android" and is contained in the parent balanced-android project folder)
- Make sure pom.xml com.balancedpayments.android....jar is selected. Click Finish.
- Right click on your project and select Properties
- Go to Android -> Library -> Add. Select balanced-android. Click Ok.

If you encounter dex errors, yo'll have to work with your dependencies to resolve the issue.

My example project is also a maven project. If yours is not and you want to convert it to one, right click the project and select Maven -> Convert to maven project. You can then open pom.xml and add the following to satisfy dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If your project uses maven, you'll probably want your Java Build Path -> Default output folder to be `/bin/classes`. I ran into Android errors when this was set to `/target/...`

Ref: https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/guides/mobile/#balanced-android